# How to move Clearpath Husky A200 by a specific distance by publishing to a topic?

Tags: navigation, clearpath, a200, husky, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I looked at some tutorials online, and I came across -

```
rostopic pub /husky/cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist
```

That does the trick well, when you specify the parameters, if I wish to keep the robot moving I believe. But I want to move it forward based on distance. Like move forward by 0.5m with 0.1 velocity and stop. What's the most direct way to do so?

I am avoiding creating a separate node for this and keeping it simple. Please let me know if more details are required.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211969/how-to-move-clearpath-husky-a200-by-a-specific-distance-by-publishing-to-a-topic?/) by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 237 on 2015-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Writing a simple node in rospy is probably the fastest way to get this done. The Husky driver itself doesn't have any position inputs, but it does publish a standard odometry topic which you can subscribe to to check an estimate of distance traveled purely based on encoders.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2015-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2015-06-29**:
Thank you. Using this [reference](https://support.clearpathrobotics.com/hc/en-us/articles/201644249-Creating-a-workspace-package-and-publisher) I am trying to get this done at the moment and will update accordingly. But is there any specific reason why you didn't allow for position in

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2015-06-30**:
The skid-steer/off-road nature of the platform means that ded-reckoned turns can't be performed with any accuracy whatsoever. As well, since the majority of users wrap some kind of high-level autonomy around it, we didn't want to add a feature which would go unused at best and confuse users at worst

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2015-07-10**:
Aah okay. Thank you! And I created a node instead which basically just moves the robot forward for couple of seconds using the geometry_msgs/Twist for now. It's working properly. Will check out the odometry topic too later. Thanks!